# Does every integer appear in the modular sum sequence?

Tags: integer-sequences, recreational-mathematics, infinite-sequences

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$Let $\N$ denote the set of non-negative integers. We inductively define a sequence $a:\N\to\N$ by:

- $a(0) = 0, a(1) = 1$ and
- $a(n) = \big(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a(k)\big)\text{ mod } n$, for $n\geq 2$.

This sequence starts with $0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 4, 2, 3,...$; more members can be calculated with [this ${\mathtt{C}}$ file](https://github.com/dominiczypen/Modular_sum_sequence/blob/main/modular_sum.c). So far this sequence doesn't seem to be listed in the [online encyclopedia of integer sequences (OEIS)](https://oeis.org/).

**Question.** Is $a$ surjective? If yes, is $a^{-1}(\{m\})$ infinite for all $m\in\N$?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A094405

Comment: Having computed the first $10^9$ terms, it seems that, say, $19$ and $39$ are missing from this sequence.

Comment: @hoboonsuan amazing, thanks! I entered the first few numbers in the OEIS search engine and came up with nothing

Comment: a common trick is to search for your sequence with the first or first few terms omitted — i learned this the hard way when i submitted a sequence i thought was new to the OEIS only to be told that it was already on the OEIS, just without my first term

Comment: Remarkable @Seva thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence is not surjective and indeed, all of its terms starting from $a_{397}$ are equal to $97$.

Let $S_n:=a_0+\dotsb+a_{n}$.

**Claim.** We have $a_n=97$ and $S_n=97n+194$ for all $n\ge397$.

Once stated, this is easy to prove by induction.

*Proof:* The case $n=397$ is verified by a computation. Applying the induction hypothesis, we get
$$ a_{n+1}\equiv S_n \equiv 97n+194 \equiv 97\pmod{n+1}. $$
Since both $a_{n+1}$ and $97$ reside in $[0,n-1]$, we have in fact $a_{n+1}=97$. Consequently, $S_{n+1}=S_n+a_{n+1}=(97n+194)+97=97(n+1)+194$.

Comment: Interestingly this was mentioned in a comment in the above-linked OEIS entry https://oeis.org/A094405: "Theorem. For all values of n>=397, a(n)=97. Proof. Let s(n) denote Sum[a(i), i=1..n-1]. Calculation shows that s(397)=38606=397*97+97. Thus a(397)=397*97+97 mod 397=97. Then s(398)=s(397)+97=398*97+97, giving a(398)=97. A simple inductive argument shows that a(397+k)=97 for all integers k>=0. - John W. Layman, Jun 07 2004"

Comment: @SamHopkins  WOW! A bad habit to start working on a problem without studying what have other people  done...